# Is it possible to expand Asana's workspaces/<id>/projects to include created_at?

Tags: restsharp, asana

I can't seem to find the magic keystrokes to make it happen. I'm using RestSharp in a .NET application if that makes a difference, but I'll be happy to know for now if it's even possible. If not, I can always pull the exact details for each project one at a time if I have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

By default, sub-objects and objects returned from queries are returned in compact form, which usually means just the name and id. You can specify the fields you want using the `opt_fields` option to your query. See https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options for more info.

In your case, try adding the query parameter `opt_fields=created_at`.

Comment: I have definitely added opt_fields=created_at to the url.. https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/833641379800/projects?opt_fields=created_at

But it still only ever returns the name and id. Still messing with it as we speak.

Comment: Oh smack! Clicking on that URL just showed the created_at field in the page that popped up! Lemme see dig in and see what just happened.

Comment: OKOKOKOK. I was using opt_expand and not getting the results I was expecting. I was thinking that opt_expand=created_at would give me name and id, but also add created_at to the list. It appears opt_expand isn't doing anything for me.